# Writing the output of Batch Queries to Kafka for Spark version 2.1.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-2.1.1

Can somebody give me pointers on how can I load the output of Batch Queries to kafka.

I researched a lot in stackoverflow and other articles but I was unable to find anything for Spark 2.1.1 .

For higher versions of spark, there is an easy way to load ([link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-the-output-of-batch-queries-to-kafka) ) . However I need to do the operation in Spark 2.1.1 .

Thank you .